# "npm run lint" fails with ELIFECYCLE (errno 3)

Tags: node.js, angular, lint

We have an Angular project and `npm run lint` works when executed on my computer, but fails with ELIFECYCLE when I run on our build server.

Full error:

```
13 verbose stack Exit status 3
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:160:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v9.5.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3
```

Why is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by updating Node.js on my build server from v9.5.0 to the latest stable. On my computer I had v10.16.0, which is why it wasn't failing there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have same Node.js version on your server and on build server.

In my case I have solved the issue by downgrading Node.js on build server from version 16.* to 14.*.

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3
```